Can get latest log file based on write time but can't read contents of the log file from remote server
In trying to retrieve the last 10 log entries of several remote servers I have:
$prod_relational_datastore = @('computer1', 'computer2')
foreach ($hostname in $prod_relational_datastore)
{
    $path = "D:\arcgisdatastore\logs\$($hostname).domain\server"
    Write-Host 'Searching '$path' for latest log file' -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $log = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock {(Get-Childitem -Path "D:\arcgisdatastore\logs$($hostname)" -Recurse -Filter server*.log| Select-Object -Last 1).Name}
    $file = $path+'\'+$log
    Write-Host $file -ForegroundColor Red
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock {Get-Content $file -tail 10}
}
    

Which returns:
Searching  D:\arcgisdatastore\logs\computer1.domain\server for latest log file
D:\arcgisdatastore\logs\computer1.domain\server\server-20241102.081002-7712-0.0.log
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : computer1
 
Searching  D:\arcgisdatastore\logs\computer2.domain\server for latest log file
D:\arcgisdatastore\logs\computer2.domain\server\server-20241102.081019-8820-0.0.log
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : computer2

However
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer1 -ScriptBlock {Get-Content 'D:\arcgisdatastore\logs\computer1.domain\server\server-20241102.081002-7712-0.0.log' -tail 10}

Returns
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:27,80" type="INFO" code="110608" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Starting backup of webhooks database 'webhooks'...</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:27,537" type="INFO" code="110609" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Webhooks database 'webhooks' was backed up successfully.</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:27,537" type="INFO" code="110608" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Starting backup of webhooks database 'webhooks'...</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:27,988" type="INFO" code="110609" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Webhooks database 'webhooks' was backed up successfully.</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:27,988" type="INFO" code="110608" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Starting backup of webhooks database 'webhooks'...</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:28,471" type="INFO" code="110609" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Webhooks database 'webhooks' was backed up successfully.</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:28,471" type="INFO" code="110608" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Starting backup of webhooks database 'webhooks'...</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:28,931" type="INFO" code="110609" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Webhooks database 'webhooks' was backed up successfully.</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:28,931" type="INFO" code="110608" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Starting backup of webhooks database 'webhooks'...</Msg>
<Msg time="2024-11-07T00:01:29,387" type="INFO" code="110609" source="Data Store" process="3404" thread="26" methodName="" machine="computer1.domain" user="" elapsed="0.0" requestID="">Webhooks database 'webhooks' was backed up successfully.</Msg>

As expected.
What am I doing wrong with the last line (12)?

Not sure if the path is the mounted D: drive on the local machine or the D: drive on the remote machine.  Don't use the mounted disk (D:) to get file on local machine.  Instead use the server name \servername\c:\path (or D:).  You may not have permission so if you are an admin replace the colon with a dollar sign \servername\c$\path

Try: $Using:file

EDIT: corrected for joining paths inside the remote command.
Stinks of invisible characters messing up or problem passing variables for some reason.
Try this:
$prod_relational_datastore = 'computer1' , 'computer2'

foreach ($hostname in $prod_relational_datastore) {
    # Let's prepare the paths variables in advance for easier debug.   
    $DomainServerPath = "D:\arcgisdatastore\logs\$($hostname).domain\server"
    $LogNamesPath = "D:\arcgisdatastore\logs$($hostname)"

    Write-Host 'Searching '$LogNamesPath' for latest log file' -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # Passing variables through -ArgumentList is the safer option.   
    $LatestLogName = Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $LogNamesPath -ScriptBlock { 
        $LogNamesPath = $args[0]
        Get-ChildItem -Path $LogNamesPath -Recurse -Filter server*.log | 
            # Because you already are using Select-Object there is no need 
            # to encapsulate, just expand the property you need.   
            Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name
    } -ComputerName $Hostname 

    Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $DomainServerPath, $LatestLogName -ScriptBlock { 

        # Use Join-Path to minimize typing mistakes.   
        $LogFilePath = Join-Path -Path $args[0] -ChildPath $args[1]

        Write-Host $LogFilePath -ForegroundColor Red

        # Evaluate adding error control in case the file is not actually there.  
        Get-Content -Path $LogFilePath -Tail 10  
    } -ComputerName $Hostname 
            
            
}
    


$LogFilePath = Join-Path -Path $DomainServerPath -ChildPath $LatestLogName fails with Join-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'D' does not exist.

@tpcolson corrected, by moving the Join-Path inside the scriptblock and passing both components as arguments
